# Can I get JSON response instead of xml? in ASIs3bucketRequest

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

I am using following code to get list of items in s3-bucket:

```
ASIS3BucketRequest *request = [ASIS3BucketRequest requestWithBucket:@"my-bucket"];
NSString *key = kS3SecretKey;
[request setSecretAccessKey:key];
key = kS3AccessKey;
[request setAccessKey:key];
[request setMaxResultCount:50]; // Max number of results we want
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestContentListFromBuckeFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestContentListFromBuckeSuccessfull:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

**When I receive the respose and log it. It is in the form of xml**

```
-(void) requestContentListFromBuckeSuccessfull: (id) request
{
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request responseData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response=%@",response);

}
```

**My question is can I set the request to receive JSON response?**

Answer (score 1):

No

You cannot get s3 response in json. Amazon S3 do not support json response. For this purpose you have to use xml parser in your objective C code.

Comment: That's bad but I think you are right. Thank you for your answer.